# Extract content from the url and show selected content

Tags: php, codeigniter

If user likes a fashion product on any site (for example:macys.com etc) and provides the url in a text box.Is it feasible to fetch the all content from given url and extract the product images and details from the content?

To start with I have tried to get the data using `file_get_contents($url)` but it is partial compare to what I get from browser's `view source`.
**For Example:**

```
url = http://goo.gl/SJZ6o
```

Tried printing it using:

```
print "<pre>". $file_get_contents($url)."</pre>";
```

I am confused with how to approach this requirement. Should I develop a browser plugin and extract with the help of that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is partial..."? Can you show an example?

Comment: They use quite a bit of JavaScript. Are you sure the product contents are not being generated client-side? If so, PHP can not grab such content unless you use a PHP JS extension.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called web scraping and can't really be covered in a simple answer. One place to start would be using PHP's Curl library instead of file_get_contents() (which should not start with a $ btw).